# Spring MVC implement "go to page" form with Thymeleaf

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, get, thymeleaf

I have a list shown in my view which is populated from my database and it uses pagination. Works fine so far. What I want to do now is to give the user the possibility to jump to a specific page via input into a text field.

My controller method would look like this, as my imagination goes:

```
@Controller
public class OrderController {

private static final int INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE = 15;
private int currentPage = 1;

@Autowired
private OrderService service;

@GetMapping("/dispo/orderViewList/{pageNumber}")
private String showSpecifiedPage(@RequestParam("pageNumber") Integer page, Model model) {
    Page<LoadOrders> pagedList = service.findAll(page -1, INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE);
    List<LoadOrder> orderList = service.createLoadOrderPage(pagedList);

    model.addAttribute("page", orderList);
    model.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
    model.addAttribute("totalPages", pagedList.getTotalPages());

    return "/dispo/orderViewList";
}
```

My idea is now since I have a model attribute named "page" to change this attribute to the page number I'd like to show and send this as a get request to the controller method. And this is the code for the view:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/dispo/orderViewList/{page}}" method="get">
    Direkt zu Seite: <input type="text" th:field ="*{page}" size ="4"> <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

The result is just what I wanted and looks like this:

[image]

But the controller is never called. In fact the controller for the standard list is called:

```
@GetMapping("/dispo/orderViewList")
private String showOrderList(@RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> page, Model model) {
    page.ifPresent(p -> currentPage = p);

    Page<LoadOrders> pagedList = service.findAll(currentPage - 1, INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE);
    List<LoadOrder> orderList = service.createLoadOrderPage(pagedList); 

    model.addAttribute("page", orderList);
    model.addAttribute("currentPage", currentPage);
    model.addAttribute("totalPages", pagedList.getTotalPages());
    return "/dispo/orderViewList";
}
```

So what can I do to tell the controller to use the method with the page parameter?

Comment: Thymeleaf paramaters are server side. What you are trying to achieve is client side and cannot be done using Thymeleaf, but should be done using JavaScript.

Comment: gna... I hoped I could avoid that. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: Your current form will always call the showOrderList method with the RequestParam being the page. If you want a default listing and one with request param then you can specify this in the @GetMapping.params

Comment: Nope, there is no way to generate that link (without using javascript).  That being said, you could make a controller that takes `{page}` as a get parameter and just redirects to `/dispo/orderViewList/{page}`.

Comment: Ok, thank you both for your help. So I will fight myself through the javascript madness.